# Install next most recent version of node module if the very latest is unavailable

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-registry

We have a local npm registry that is updated as and when requests are made to it.

This can results in failures because it knows `foo-sorter@1.2.3` is out there, but hasn't synced it yet. Even if we only specify `foo-sorter@^1.1.0` (forgive me if the semver is wrong) in out `package.json`, and we could get that.

I'm not in control of the registry, but if there was a way of telling NPM **"`Install next most recent version of node module if the very latest is unavailable`"**, so if it fail to get `foo-sorter@1.2.3` then it tries to get `foo-sorter@1.2.1` or `foo-sorter@1.1.5`, then I could prevent build failures more often.

Is that an option? If not how else could I get it happen?